# Write a x86 (32-bit) assembler program that sends prime numbers from 1 to 100,000 to standard output

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I want to write a x86 (32-bit) assembler program that sends prime numbers from 1 to 100,000 to standard output. I wrote some code but it seems to not work properly.

```
section .data
    msg db 'The next prime number is: ', 0
    len equ $-msg

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 1      ; current number
    mov edx, 1      ; divisor
    mov ecx, 100000 ; upper limit

find_next_prime:
    cmp eax, edx
    je print_number
    inc edx
    cmp edx, eax
    jg check_next_number
    mov ebx, eax
    xor edx, edx
    div edx, edx
    cmp edx, 0
    je not_prime
    jmp check_next_number

not_prime:
    inc eax
    jmp find_next_prime

check_next_number:
    cmp eax, ecx
    jl find_next_prime

print_number:
    ; Print message
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, len
    int 0x80

    ; Print number
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, eax
    mov edx, 10
    int 0x80

    ; Exit
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

I am new to assembly language so i don't know what can I do to get this working. Maybe someone could fix this code and tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: "Does not work properly" is not a good problem description. Anyway, obvious issues are: 1) after printing a number you exit 2) you don't convert the number to text at all 3) printing destroys registers you need 4) check_next_number falls through into `print_number`. 5) you use `read` syscall for printing 6) you do not pass an address. Maybe more problems. PS: Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Debug it.  Debugging assembly language is like debugging most other languages: step line by line and verify program state in between each step.  Program state starts with register values (though also includes memory for globals, heap, and stack).  The instruction pointer register is also very important as it says what instruction to run next.  If your program has any one wrong instruction or is missing one, it won't run right.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your problem is here:

```
find_next_prime:
    cmp eax, edx
    je print_number
    inc edx
    cmp edx, eax
    jg check_next_number
    mov ebx, eax
    xor edx, edx          ;mov edx,0
    div edx, edx          ;divide zero by zero
    cmp edx, 0
    je not_prime
    jmp check_next_number
```

I'm not familiar with 32-bit x86 (I've only ever used the 16-bit version), but I can tell you that if you divide anything by zero, you're not going to get the desired result.

[Here's how div works in x86.](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div.html)

Comment: That's correct.  Furthermore, `div edx` is guaranteed to #UD fault for *any* value of EDX, not just 0, because the quotient won't fit in the operand-size.  (Exactly the same as `div dx`, `div rdx`, or `div ah`.)